# Trying to set listView in fragment with string array from parse

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-listview, parse-platform

I am trying to set ListView in my fragment. The resourse that I am trying to show is from  my class in Parse. when I am trying to show it, I get errors about there is no resourcse yet. The reason  according to what I understand is the download infromation from parse taking more time than the app to show the the list.. so the app trying to show String array which is null. what should I do?

Comment: Are you retrieving the data asynchronously?

Comment: No, how should I do this? @stkent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be retrieving data from Parse using the [`findInBackground`](https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseQuery.html#findInBackground(com.parse.FindCallback)) method. Update your UI (in this case, populate your ListView with the retrieved data) inside the [`FindCallback`](https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/FindCallback.html) you provide when initiating the request. This way you can be sure that you only attempt to interact with your UI when data is available.

Comment: relly tnx man! I been trying to find a way to solve this problem for two weeks